# How to store a selected value in a grid view to hidden field or session

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, postback

I am having this button in a gridview_MessageTable

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_ViewDashBoard" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/dash.png" Enabled="True"
                                    Width="50" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("MsgID", "ResponseMetric.aspx?MsgID={0}") %>'
                                    Text='Send'></asp:ImageButton>
```

On click it postback with the selected value.

How can I store that value in a session or a hidden field in server side.

Comment: using Session["selectedVal"] = value; ?

Comment: hidden field or session are different things, once is page related and the other is user session related. What do you want to do with that value and from where do you want to use it?

Comment: I want to pass the selected value to a query string. I am not able to access the value in the redirected page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PostBackUrl='<%# String.format("ResponseMetric.aspx?MsgID={0}", Eval("MsgID")) %>'
```

You should be able to retrieve the value in `ResponseMetric.aspx` in the following way:

```
string msgID = Request.QueryString["MsgID"];
```

Comment: How to save that value in session in ResponseMetric.aspx

Comment: @Gokul, to save in session do this: Session["ANYKEYYOUCHOOSE"]=msgID;

Comment: @Gokul: i don't understand, i've showed how to get the value via Request.QueryString. Does this not work? You could also use the [PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) Property. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178139.aspx

Comment: @Gokul: Are you sure that you need to store the value in the redirected page in the Session? If you are anyway use a QueryString-Parameter to transfer that value, you could also add it to the QueryString when you want to go back. If you want to use the Session anyway, i would handle the ImageButton's click-event (and drop the `PostBackURL` approach) to store it in Session and then `Response.Redirect` to `ResponseMetric.aspx`.